# Bookdown custom blocks in MS Word (word_document2)

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I have a R markdown `.Rmd` document that includes [custom blocks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/custom-blocks.html):

```
---
title: "My MRE"
author: "Me"
output:
  bookdown::word_document2:
    reference_docx: template.docx
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
  bookdown::html_document2:
    css: style.css
---

Some plain text

::: {.mystyle data-latex=""}
Content with style applied
:::
```

Adding a `mystyle` class to the linked `style.css` and `preamble.tex` produces the desired output in HTML and PDF formats.

I am not sure how to specify the format for `mystyle` in `template.docx`: I've created a style named `mystyle` but this is not applied to the relevant blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have just spent hours trying to add `bookdown::word_document2:` as an option, and after lots of tests I finally found that the spacial block are the culprit (by elimitating Rmd files one by one.) I found where the problem was as the *.knit.md file was not deleted and where the problems occur the text looks like it's a binary file!

These blocks are defined in a different way in the Rmd as *e.g.* `{block, type="rmdexercise"}` and then defined in a Latex preamble as an `\newenvironment{rmdblock}[1]` and many other lines. There are also similar `:::` blocks that probably cause the same problem.

Creating multi-formats documents is perhaps a luxury... but it's quite a nice treat when it works. If anyone has a solution to this it would be awesome! Thanks. JYS